# Excel file represented by string in API response: how to download as file with python?

Tags: python-3.x, python-requests

I am calling an API that returns the following object as response:

```
{
    "BrokenRules": [],
    "ReturnCode": 0,
    "ReturnData": "\"UEsDBBQAAAAIAGJAylC560mkEgIAAM4DAAAPABwAeGwvd29ya2Jvb2sueG1sIKIYACigFAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAO29B2AcSZYlJi9tynt/SvVK1+B0oQiAYBMk2JBAEOzBiM3mku.....ASAMAABMAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA0P8QAFtDb250ZW50X1R5cGVzXS54bWxQSwUGAAAAAAgACAD9AQAAqAERAAAA\""

}
```

I am supposed to be able to download an excel file (.xlsx) from the ReturnData object. How do I do that with python 3?

Here is what I have tried, but the file is corrupt and is empty. Any ideas ?

```
filename = "api_output.xlsx"
response = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, json=data)
    res = json.loads(response.json()["ReturnData"]) 

    with open(filename, 'w') as file:
        print("writing file")
        file.write(res)
```

Comment: what are you trying to do here? `json.loads(response.json()["ReturnData"]) `

Comment: to get the string object

Comment: why not simply use `response.json()["ReturnData"]`?

Comment: I did that, but that didn't work either

Answer (score 0):

So I found the answer:

```
response = requests.post(URL, headers=headers, json=data)
res = json.loads(response.json()["ReturnData"])
data = base64.b64decode(res)
with open(filename, 'wb') as file:
    print("writing file")
    file.write(data)
```